# How to call eslint without positional arguments

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

From what I understand, `eslint`, or better `typescript-eslint`, can read `tsconfig.json`.  This seems to work for me.

But I cannot call `eslint` without a positional argument specifying the files that should be linted. I cannot find any documentation on how to call `eslint` correctly without specifying the files again.

Specifying the files again is a maintenance nightmare.  I could work around this by using `jq` to extract the correct field from `tsconfig.json`, but this seems like such a hack.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/853 suggests that the `includes` from `tsconfig.json` should be respected?  But there is no sample of how `eslint` is called.

Edit:
To put in simple words: I would like to call `npm run eslint`, not `npm run eslint path/to/ts/files`.

2. Edit:
   I'm using

```sh
FILES=`jq -r ".include[] |= \"${PROJECT_ROOT}/\" + . + \" \" | .include | add" "${PROJECT_ROOT}/tsconfig.json"`
```

and then `npm run eslint $FILES` as a workaround.

Comment: To me it isn't really clear what you want to do. Please consider to clarify your question.

Comment: Hope the edit helps!

Answer (score 0):

How does your `package.json` look like? You could specify your path there like this:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "eslint": "eslint path/to/ts/files"
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas this doesn't help.  I don't want to repeat myself by specifying the files twice since this will lead to things possibly being only added to `tsconfig.json` later on, not to `package.json`.